# how to move pending changelist file to default with command

Tags: command-line, perforce

I'm preparing python script for check the pending default is empty or not. if has I will put them all in a new pending change-list, after I done by other operation. I need put this pending change-list file back to default.

but I don't know how to put the specify change-list back to default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To move a file (`//depot/foo`) from the default changelist to an (already created) numbered changelist (1234), use

```
p4 reopen -c 1234 //depot/foo
```

To move it from 1234 back into the default changelist, use

```
p4 reopen -c default //depot/foo
```

Comment: if there still has any other pending change-list under this path, but I don't want put them to default, does it work?

Comment: No, it will grab all the files that are already opened (checked out), regardless of which changelists they are opened in, and will move them to the changelist you specify.

Answer (score 6):

```
p4 -F %depotFile% opened -c CHANGE | p4 -x - reopen -c default
```

i.e. get all files opened in CHANGE, then reopen them in the default changelist.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following command to move a file from a known change list to the default.

p4 reopen -c default file_path

moving between changelists is described [here](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_reopen.html).